# NSSearchField doesn't become first responder in OS X 10.11

Tags: focus, nssearchfield

I have a question about NSSearchField, the question is that NSSearchField doesn't have focus when it become first responder, and the focus is on the button which is next to NSSearchField in Xib file. 
And this happens only in OS X 10.11, it's normal in OS X 10.10 and previous versions.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_11SearchField

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsresponder/1526750-becomefirstresponder), we should never invoke `[NSView setFirstresponder]` directly, and involving it may raises an exception.

In order to set first responder to a view, `[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:];` should be used instead,